# Datagrid autoheight + lazy loading

Tags: lazy-loading, dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a Dojo Datagrid which has 10 columns and about 400 records of data... it doesn't seem like that much but it is very very slow to scroll...

I have another Datagrid which has some 5k records and it scrolls faster. The only difference between the two is that for one I am specifying the height in pixels and have autoheight turned off...

For the smaller one, I couldn't use height = 100% to fill up its parent div because for some reason it doesn't like a percent height and doesn't even render the grid if I specify a percent height - I have to give it in pixels... if I use autoheight = true, then it fills up its parent div which is what I want but then it loads ALL data in the grid at once and so it doesn't do any lazy loading of the data.

Any ideas how to achieve lazy loading and still be able to use autoheight = true (or be able to expand the grid so that it always fills up the height of its parent div)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

autoHeight can be set to a numeric value, which will define the maximum number of rows to display